# Выполнение функции (процедуры) по расписанию

Tags: 1с, cron

Хочется что-то вроде cron'a.

Как делаю: Конфигуратор->Общие->Общие модули-> создаю свой модуль с процедурой (название `ПользовательскийМодуль`):

```
Процедура ОтчетПартнеровПроцедура (Объект) Экспорт
      //Объект.Записать()
КонецПроцедуры
```

Потом Конфигуратор->Регламентные задания->Создаю задание "Отчет партнеров".

Открываю список медотов, но ни самого модуля под названием `"ПользовательскийМодуль"`, ни процедуры `"ОтчетПартнеровПроцедура"`.

Как добавить процедуру в расписание? Хочется запускать каждый вечер рабочего дня.

Comment: Фак ми, нужно было отключить галку "Глобальный".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вот [здесь](http://howknow1c.ru/programmirovanie-1c/reglamentnye-zadanija-1s.html) все подробно описано

В интернетах [много информации](http://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&gs_nf=3&gs_rn=0&gs_ri=hp&cp=23&gs_id=6&xhr=t&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+1%D1%81&pf=p&newwindow=1&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+1%D0%A1&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=f8d15b261fce276c&bpcl=39650382&biw=1600&bih=1065) по данной теме

**UPD**

Я тут на днях написал приложение на delphi + добавил пару обработчиков в две 1С'ки, которые позволили автоматизировать процесс трансфера данных между базами. Я просто указываю базы, период, по каким дням и в какое время производить обмен данными, жму "старт", сворачиваю программу в трей и занимаюсь своими делами :)

Comment: Да вроде как первую статью читал. Посмотримс.

Comment: Хрен там два, читал я всю эту лобуду вроде. Нет модуля в списке:

![http://upyourpic.org/images/201211/bkivkh7bjp.png][1]
  [1]: http://upyourpic.org/images/201211/bkivkh7bjp.png